# Rxjava2, how to invoke/notify onNext() Observable source's Observer from within another observable

Tags: observable, observers, rx-java2

Im not quite sure if my question title is correct, Ill just try to explain it and will be gladly appreciate any correction.

So I have this snippet (pseudo like),

**Some observer outside**

```
Observer someObserverOutside = new Observer() {

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {}

        @Override
        public void onNext(Object o) {

            // "Ok value" recieved here
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

            // BadThrowable received here
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {}
    };
```

My Observable stream

```
Observable
            .defer( create new observable for observer/subscription )
            .retry( apply a funtion that will retry when some A error happened )

                           -> apply {

                                Observable
                                        .defer (create new observable for observer/subscription )
                                        .retry( apply a funtion that will retry when some B error happened )

                                                -> apply {

                                                    if (OK) {
                                                        someObserverOutside.onNext("Ok Value");
                                                    } else {
                                                        Observable.error(throw some BadThrowable)
                                                    }
                                                }
            .subscribe(someObserverOutside);
```

My Goal is for any operator I applied or any observable source I create for the original observable, any good operation should notify the source's **observer**, just as how **Observable.error(Throwable)** ***notifies*** the outer observer for any error.

My question is, is this a **good** design? is this the proper way? or is there a good approach to achieve what I want?,everything is going smoothly, but ofcourse we have this gut feeling if were not sure, so I decided to post a question as I cant think of a good search "term" for my issue.

Any help or link would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to implement oauth?

Comment: yep I am, and this is part of the previous issues(posts) I had when renewing an invalid token